# Нужна помощь в написании легкого скрипта для сортировки файла с логами

Tags: linux, bash, shell, консоль

Имеется вот такой вот файл с логами (https://files.fm/u/pquef4uk)
И имеется вот такой вот кусок кода от меня -

```
grep "GET" cdlinux.www.log | cut -d'[' -f2,4 | sort | uniq | grep ".iso" | grep -o "cdlinux-.*" | cut -d" " -f1 | uniq | sort | uniq -c
```

На выходе получается вот такое(работаю в терминале на macOs) -

```
   4 cdlinux-0.5.7-pre2.iso
   1 cdlinux-0.5.7-pre2.iso"
   4 cdlinux-0.5.7-pre4.iso
   2 cdlinux-0.5.8-rc2.iso
  43 cdlinux-0.5.8.iso
   2 cdlinux-0.5.8.iso"
   2 cdlinux-duzy.changelog
   3 cdlinux-duzy.dpkg-l
   1 cdlinux-maly-0.5.7-pre2.iso
  50 cdlinux-maly-0.5.8-rc1.iso
   1 cdlinux-maly-current.iso
   2 cdlinux-maly.changelog
   4 cdlinux-maly.dpkg-l
```

Суть кода в том что он якобы считает сколько раз была скачана версия linux'a с веб-сайта на каждый айпи(то есть код должен исключать повторные скачивания с одного и того же айпи адреса). Как видите у меня есть ошибки в коде, так как результат не очень похож на правду. Мог бы кто-нибудь помочь мне написать этот код, используя только те команды которые и так имеются в моем? В результате должно быть так -

(количество скачиваний версии) (название версии).

Буду благодарен за подсказки и помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас как-то сложно.

```bash
grep -o 'GET [^"]*\.iso' cdlinux.www.log | grep -o 'cdlinux-.*' | sort | uniq -c
```

Результат:

```
     13 cdlinux-0.5.7-pre2.iso
      8 cdlinux-0.5.7-pre4.iso
    902 cdlinux-0.5.8-1.iso
  55138 cdlinux-0.5.8-2.iso
      2 cdlinux-0.5.8-2xxx.iso
    615 cdlinux-0.5.8.iso
      6 cdlinux-0.5.8-rc2.iso
      1 cdlinux-duzy-0.5.8-2.iso
    869 cdlinux-duzy-current.iso
     54 cdlinux-maly-0.5.7-pre2.iso
  14049 cdlinux-maly-0.5.8.iso
    481 cdlinux-maly-0.5.8-rc1.iso
   4908 cdlinux-maly-0.5.9-pre1.iso
     64 cdlinux-maly-current.iso
```

---

Уникальные по айпишникам можно найти так:

```
cat cdlinux.www.log |
  sed -n 's/[^:]*:\([^ ]*\) .*GET.*\(cdlinux-[^"]*\.iso \).*/\1 \2/p' |
  uniq | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort |
  xargs -I + basename -s .iso + | uniq -c
```

Результат:

```
     11 cdlinux-0.5.7-pre2
      7 cdlinux-0.5.7-pre4
    466 cdlinux-0.5.8-1
  19692 cdlinux-0.5.8-2
      1 cdlinux-0.5.8-2xxx
     84 cdlinux-0.5.8
      6 cdlinux-0.5.8-rc2
      1 cdlinux-duzy-0.5.8-2
    453 cdlinux-duzy-current
     15 cdlinux-maly-0.5.7-pre2
   5024 cdlinux-maly-0.5.8
    106 cdlinux-maly-0.5.8-rc1
   2260 cdlinux-maly-0.5.9-pre1
     24 cdlinux-maly-current
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, только мне вот повторные скачивания не нужны были, поэтому я немного поменял ваш скрипт
{ grep -o 'GET [^"]*\.iso' cdlinux.www.log | uniq |  grep -o 'cdlinux-.*' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/.iso//'  }
Ну и убрал .iso с итога.

Comment: @AliakseiKlimovich Не заметил условия про айпишник. См. мою правку, так более верно.

Comment: Почему на macOs я получаю такую ошибку, вы не знаете? (sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence). Когда запускаю скрипт на Ubuntu, такого не происходит.

Comment: @AliakseiKlimovich Я видел у вас там в логе где-то неверный UTF-8. Возможно, на это жалуется. Проведите через валидатор.

Comment: Да и у вас как-то сложно.